# iPerf3 on wsl can be a client but cannot be a server

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, iperf, iperf3

I run iperf from my computer on linux subsystem on windows, and transmist to a mobile phone that can accept iPerf. Both devices are on same network, and on iPerf3. My computer has version iPerf3.9.

I can use the computer as a client and the mobile phone as the server as shown successfully

However, once I set the computer as the server, it could not hear a thing. and the mobile phone who is the client has a problem said '**unable to connect to server: Connection refused**'.

I try to set this

```
wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2
```

to version 2, as it allows me to have TCP congestion control of reno cubic. Or else if I set it to version 1 on PowerShell administration mode

```
wsl --set-version Ubuntu 1
```

my iperf3 on the computer will not have TCP congestion control

What should I do to make the computer on the ubuntu subsystem and mobile phone can test the iPerf?

P.S. I also tried the windows version as well, however it has the same problem of having no TCP_congestion_control as the newest version of windows I could find is iPerf3.1 which I have found on some websites that have this issue.

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines. Three of your images can be replaced by text.

Answer (score -1):

> `wsl --set-version Ubuntu 1` 
> my iperf3 on the computer will **not have TCP congestion control**

This issue was fixed in iperf3 3.10.

> However, once I set the computer as the server, it could not hear a thing. and the mobile phone who is the client has a problem said '**unable to connect to server: Connection refused**'.

It may be that the network/system routing tables are not set properly to allow routing from the mobile to the WSL.

Also, what IP address are you using to connect to the iperf3 server under WSL?  It should be the "... src " from the `ip route list` command under WSL.  This should also be the IP that the server on the mobile shows when it receive a connection from the WSL client.  If the IPs are different, then probably a NAT changes the original IP and routing tables should be set accordingly.